# Cannot upgrade linux kernel due to space, but cannot remove older ones

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt

```
uname -r

5.15.0-60-generic
```

My apt upgrade is failing with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  mc libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra node-hosted-git-info imagemagick libzmq5
  python2.7-minimal libmagickwand-6.q16-6 python2.7 python3-rsa mc-data
  node-tar imagemagick-6.q16 libeditorconfig0 libjs-jquery-ui libopenexr24
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libmysofa1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 glances libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.36) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

1. First of all, I'm a little confused by this. I seem to be ON 5.15.0-60-generic already, why is it trying to

```
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic with 1.
```

?

2. I presume this is due to low disk space:

```
df -H

Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       135G     0  135G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       28G  3.0M   28G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  982G  838G   94G  90% /
tmpfs                      136G  296M  135G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      136G     0  136G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2             738M  588M   97M  86% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             536M  6.4M  530M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2                  7.0T  1.5T  5.2T  23% /mnt/usb-8tb
tmpfs                       28G   25k   28G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs                       28G   70k   28G   1% /run/user/1000
```

So I'm trying to remove old linux kernels, which seems to be taking space:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n  | grep linux-image
20      linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
9520    linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic
9927    linux-image-5.11.0-36-generic
9928    linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic
9933    linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic
9956    linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic
9956    linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic
9965    linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic
9965    linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic
9965    linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic
9968    linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic
9968    linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
9971    linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic
9971    linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic
9971    linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic
9972    linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic
9973    linux-image-5.13.0-51-generic
9973    linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic
10775   linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic
10778   linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic
11196   linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic
11207   linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic
11208   linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
11209   linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic
11210   linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic
11212   linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic
11214   linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic
11215   linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic
11223   linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic
11499   linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic
11502   linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
11502   linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic
11504   linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic
11504   linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic
```

3. But when trying to remove any of the older ones, it says it will only free up 0 bytes.

Appreciate some guidance here on those questions - many thanks.

Comment: Regardless of whether removing many of them releases 0bytes, having that many installed seems ludicrous.

Comment: Have you tried to `fsck` the disk? (example [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fsck-command-linux))

Comment: @harrymc I have not no. Is it safe to unmount the boot partition to do so? (I guess /dev/nvme0n1p2 in my case?)

  Actually, from the output above, it's not quite clear to me what's failing. Does it write to (encrypted) swap  (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1) as a temporary step, and that is what is failing?

Comment: The only time when `/boot` needs to be mounted is when you are updating the kernel. Completely possible to unmount at any time or even to set it to `noauto` in database. You can ignore the zero byte message and remove anyway. Maybe the fsck first but possibly the message is wrong.

Comment: Just nuke (eg: `: > somefile`) older initramfs files in /boot to free some space for the upgrade for your current kernel's initramfs to succeed. Then remove older kernels packages.

Comment: See https://markmcb.com/2013/02/04/cleanup-unused-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/ Also: *Edit the file '/etc/dnf/dnf.conf', changing the numeric value in **installonly_limit=3** to a number of your choosing.* See https://superuser.com/questions/1423559/how-can-i-change-the-number-of-kernels-retained-when-updating-in-fedora

Comment: dnf <- for Ubuntu? Really? I'd expect to see `apt` in there.

Comment: google "unattended upgrade ubuntu"

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption: `fsck` is ok, i.e. not complaining.*

Now,

Leave `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` in place as that is a meta-package that is used for coming updates of your ubuntu.

The other ones are just taking up space, except the one printed by `uname -r` and maybe one prior to it *(as a backup, for safety in case of malfunction in the latest)*.

These other-ones SHOULD be removable with e.g.
`sudo apt purge linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic` *(for the first in your list (above)*
you may also add more of them after the first one, just make sure there is at least one space in between each of them.

... or even do
`dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | grep linux-image >~/kernels`

Then make sure there is just names of ones to remove in that file...
*(edit with e.g. `nano ~/kernels`, leave only packages to remove in there, save the file)*
then do:

`sudo apt purge $(cat ~/kernels)`
... or similar.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm a little nervous to nuke things without understanding this bit:  " I seem to be ON 5.15.0-60-generic already, why is it trying to
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic" - any ideas?

Comment: `initramfs` is a "linux" running for a few moments while the main Linux is about to boot. And the reason for the update failure is most likely "Space too low" - the update cannot create what it needs. So: One way to free up some is to "nuke some old file" - as A.B. put it. e.g. `sudo echo >/boot/initrd.img-x.xx.x-xx-generic` for an OLD version of initrd.

Comment: so at this point initramfs is running an old kernel (NOT 5.15.0-60), while my main system is running the latest? (5.15.0-60)...?

Comment: Seems likely as installation failed.